# Can npm symlink node modules to a master directory instead of redownloading?

Tags: node.js, npm

With npm, when a package requires other packages it creates a tree structure of dependencies. Sometimes a lot of these dependencies depend on the same packages from other packages.

I was wondering, would it be possible to make npm so all packages are stores in the global node_modules and any dependency is just symlinked back to the top of the global node_modules. I understand the version issue, and that can just be handled by storing the package with the version name appended, then symlinking to the proper version.

I feel this would speed up installs and reduce disk usage for duplicate files.

(Is this what npm3 is supposed to do?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you propose would be possible (at least on Linux the symlinks are resolved as expected).

npm (in none of its versions) however does not benefit from symlinks. To gain some of the benefits you proposed, newer versions of npm work as follows: if some package is needed multiple times, npm installs the package as high as possible in the dependency tree. This enables using the same dependency by multiple packages.

For example, no matter how many (sub-)dependencies depend on somedep v. ^1.x.x you got only one copy of somedep. This will probably be placed directly in the root node_modules, so that any sub-dependency can require it.

Older versions of npm do not do this automatically, however, you can invoke the similar effect by running 'npm dedupe'.

Note however, that this approach is weaker than proposed in the question: If 3 of your dependencies depend on somedep v. ^1.x.x and 3 other dependencies depend on somedep v. ^2.x.x, npm obviously cannot put both of these somedeps to the parent node_modules.

Also, check out ied project: https://github.com/alexanderGugel/ied . It does something similar to what you propose, but sadly, it installs only one version of each dependency, which is quite limiting.